# adBannerView over UITabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.ioslearner.com/implement-iads-tutorial-iphone-ipad-sdk/), but my example is a little bit complex then the one mentioned. My example has a `TabBar` on the bottom and an `UITableViewController` above it. In this `UITableViewController` there is an `UISearchBar` (and of course a cell prototype `UITableViewCell` for the cell contents).

What I want to do is to put an `adBannerView` over the `TabBar` and under all the Cells like it's described in the link .

Hope it's clear enough for you all to understand, if not, please tell me.

thanks Dario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your adBannerView to tableview's window property. Also give proper frame to bannerview according to window.

```
[self.tableview.window addSubview:adbannerview];
```